# In Django, is using exclude() before values() actually better for performance or is it just a myth?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

In Django QuerySet, while querying, is it really better to use exclude() before values() in a query?

For example:

```
query_obj = TestModel.objects.values().exclude(somefield='somevalue')
```

Is this the right way or,

```
query_obj = TestModel.objects.exclude(somefield='somevalue').values()
```

this one?

Or both work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Model.objects` does not execute query yet. So if you start with `values()`, then it goes for all entries in a table. Then `exclude()` is executed without database query.

If you start with `exclude()` then the first database call is reduced by excluded objects. `values()` after that is executed on smaller QuerySet already. It might be usefull, especially if database is big.